# How Do I Show A Grayed Out Text Field On A Web Form With Excel VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am populating an Internet Explorer web form with Excel VBA. I am able to get all the information to successfully go into the form. However, some of the fields on the form are remaining grayed out and you can't edit it, even though they have data populated in their fields already.

Take a look at this picture as an example:

[image]

See how the phone number is populated in the field but the field remains grayed out? That is the problem. I'm looking for a way to programmatically reveal that field so that it becomes editable.

So, I was able to fix this issue with some fields by simulating a click on some dropdowns as a user would do which normally reveals the field. However, that does not work for this field as well as some others.

Here is the HTML of the field I am trying to programmatically reveal with Excel VBA.

```
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left">
<input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="97183355576083984700">
<input type="text" id="P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT" name="p_t20" value="" size="50" maxlength="255" class="text_field apex_disabled" disabled=""></td>
```

This is the code I normally use to populate data from Excel to a form field. It's setting the element ID equal to what is in its named Excel range.

```
doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").Value = Range("ContactForm").Value
```

The "Contact Info" field should look like the below. The field will turn white and it will then be editable.

[image]

I would appreciate any recommendations/advice you can give me. Or, if you know where an answer is, please point me in the right direction and I will take this one down. I could not find an answer to this question after days of research.

Comment: Did you try `doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").Disabled = False` before populating?

Comment: I have not. I will try it now!

Comment: Try to focus the textbox and than try to use sendkeys to enter value. check whether it enables the checkbox or not. Application.SendKeys ("(12345)"), True

Comment: Okay, that made it editable which is the important thing. Thank you! The only strange thing is the field doesn't go from gray to white. Any ideas on how to update that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the field with

```
doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").Disabled = False
```

And change `class="text_field apex_disabled"` to `class="text_field"` with

```
doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").className = "text_field"
```

to make it white. If that doesn't work check the `class` of an already enabled field and set this field the same class.

Comment: Incredible! The suggestion of "doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").className = "text_field" worked as well. You're the man @PEH, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by @PEH in the comments. Thank you PEH!

Answer: `doc.getElementById("P1_REPORTED_BY_CONTACT").disabled = False`

Simple, yet effective!

Comment: see my answer to remove the gray too.